# Why is the expression "1"==1 evaluating to TRUE?

Tags: r

"1" is character value and other 1 is numeric. Even, when I tried executing below line it gave me TRUE.

```
as.character("0")==as.numeric(0)
```

Can anyone help me to understand, why?

Comment: `?==` says: "If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw."

Comment: answer 'why'  is already given.. If you want to test, you can use `identical(as.character("0"),as.numeric(0))`, which results in `FALSE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `help("==")`:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

So `1` should be converted to `"1"`.